# Nuxt.js static site relative urls

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've created a new static Nuxt.js project. All the urls and paths to resources are absolute i.e. `/`. Is there an easy way to use relative urls and paths `./`?

I have a few assumptions (I'm a Java dev):

- Static Nuxt.js projects do not require a web server.
- `/file.js` is intended to be served by a web server.

The projects purpose is reading data (json files) locally and displaying the processed data (hence no web server). I'm going to add fancy graphs, forms etc... Am I using the wrong approach?

I've spent a long time googling this and I've never seen a decent answer.

Here is my nuxt.conf.js `config.output.publicPath = './_nuxt/'` seems to do half a job. It works works for `<script src="./_nuxt/936eba5.js"></script>` but not `<link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/936eba5.js" as="script">`

```js
export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,

  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'my-app',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/buefy
    'nuxt-buefy',
  ],

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (!isDev) {
        // relative links, please.
        config.output.publicPath = './_nuxt/'
      }
      return config;
    }
  },

  // router: {
  //   base: ''
  // }
}
```

---

EDIT with more information.

`_nuxt` is the default path/url that is in `/dist`.

I've only generated a project at this point and *tried* to make the urls relative.

`/dist`

- 200.html
- README.md
- _nuxt
- favicon.ico
- index.html
- inspire

So removing `config.output.publicPath = './_nuxt/'`. Using `ssr: true`. Then running `npm run generate`

These absolute url/paths are generated:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/42fc731.js" as="script">
<script src="/_nuxt/42fc731.js" defer></script>
```

It's been raised as a bug many times in Nuxt.js Github but I've never seen an actual resolution.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `<link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/936eba5.js" as="script">`?

Comment: It's generated for me in `<head>`. That link is absolute. It needs to be relative.

Comment: You know that the name of the file will change? It's probably not the way to do things here. What do you try to do exactly? Fetch some JSON or something else?

Comment: I gonna ask it again, what is the issue with _relative URL_? Why don't you keep it as is? You should totally have access to it from the usual default entry point. Also, what are the issues that you're talking about? And also, how are `<head>` and `relative URLs` related to your JSON initial project idea?

Comment: I want to use relative urls to include js/css/images etc... that's my requirement. The web app is generated with absolute urls, that's something I don't want. I mentioned an approximation of  the app does to demonstrate that I want it to be local and not use a web server. Loading JSON isn't an issue - only I want a local web app.

Comment: I should mention that the absolute path of `/` returns a 404, because I'm not using a web server.

Comment: You can also reference relative paths to your assets with this kind of syntax `~/assets/your_image.png` as shown in the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets/#images). Oh, if you're talking about running only the files, so with `file://` protocol rather than `http://`? This will not be doable because modern apps are using Webpack and a lot of things will not work properly without a proper dev/prod server running. (like any API calls) This is why you do have a `nuxt start` in your `package.json`. What is the issue with some webpack server?

Comment: I'm not using a web server. I'm running the web app by just opening the `index.html` in a web browser. I'm not running `npm run start`, hence `static`

Comment: `static` !== `file protocol`. As told above, this is not doable because the app is using webpack. When you're using the term static, you should be more precise because Nuxt do have a `static` target. What is the issue with running a webpack server? It does not take lot of resources since the app is production bundled.

Comment: The web app generates reports for developer builds. They would open a web page. It is certainly not feasible for them to run `nuxt start`

Comment: Explain your use case a bit better here please (edit your question). Who is `they`? Why can't you host it? What is the issue of an app running on production (Netlify) and getting update on whatever you're sending it?

Comment: It's a local report for a when you run Java tests. It's just a local web app/html file.

Comment: Explain your use case a bit better here. It will be targeted to devs? What is the issue with `nuxt start`?

Comment: To me seems very strange that Vue.js/Nuxt.js/Webpack can't generate a html page that can be directly opened in chrome.

Comment: I'd get lynched if I told a Java dev - just install npm, npx, nuxt etc... to view a report

Comment: Looking at [this](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6133), it looks like that the configuration is maybe doable but with various downsides. Maybe `router.base` can help here. Again, `file://` protocol may have several limitations.. Still, if you get lynched by a Java dev, just whatever. If the guy is closed-minded af, eh poor him. Still, why don't you host it somewhere? This way, no need for them to install anything. I don't get the issue here: host it, they do upload their stuff, they have the info. Or, host it locally in the company for a local result. Or make some bash install-script.

Comment: There is a lot of introduced complexity here for something that is rather simple to avoid by hosting the app. Otherwise, you could always make a vanilla .js file and dump your whole libs/logic into it if you want to have an easy access to the file with the `file://` protocol. The right tool for the right need (Nuxt may not be the good one here). Maybe Svelte can help too, since it do generate .js file at the end AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll look in to that. It could be that Nuxt.js is the wrong choice for me. It's a local report, it's not something that should be hosted.

Comment: If your JSON files are local, alright it fine. Host the app but keep the files. I mean, you can drag and drop them into your app and have the graphs and so on. You could even open-source it for other people to use. Since it will run in your browser, you'll keep your data safe and local. Otherwise, make a desktop app (electron) for this. Haha, overkill. Was just kidding.

Comment: Thank for your help, it's given me lots to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt.js doesn't appear to support relative urls (see above). However Vue3 and Vite does.

Reproduction steps:

```sh
npm install vue@next
npm install -g @vue/cli
npm init @vitejs/app my-app
```

output:

```sh
@vitejs/create-app
Ok to proceed? (y) y
✔ Select a framework: · vue
✔ Select a variant: · TypeScript
```

```sh
cd my-app
npm install
npm run build
```

vite.config.ts

```js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  base: './'
})
```

Comment: OP is using Nuxt2 here, hence Vue2.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to load some JSONs into your Nuxt app, you should use [nuxt-content](https://github.com/nuxt/content). I've actually created a boilerplate here that you can check: https://github.com/kissu/nuxt-tailwind-typography-darkmode-boilerplate

You can find 2 articles in `/content/articles`. There, you can see how to fetch then and how to display them.

Full static Nuxt do not require any server indeed. You can even SSR (`ssr: true`) it and still have it as `target: static`.

`publicPath` is not the right thing here. It should not be used, neither should you use any of the following: `_nuxt`, `.nuxt` or alike.
`yarn generate`, then deploy your `/dist` directory to a simple free platform, like [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) and you'll be gucci. You can try my project if you want (beware, there is more configuration than neeed in your case).

If you want to add something to your `head`, please follow this documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/meta-tags-seo

Comment: Thanks for your response.  `_nuxt` was the out box path/url that is in /dist.

Comment: I don't understand. What would I configure not use `_nuxt` or `.nuxt`? The web app has been generated. Deploying to netfify isn't an option for me. This is a local webapp, it is not meant to be run on a server.

Comment: `.nuxt` is used for caching purposes, knowing that would be a good enough reason for you to not use it. `_nuxt` is, as you told, used in `/dist`. The starting point of any modern app nowadays is `index.html` or `index.js`, from where you do load/hydrate your app as an SPA. I'm not sure why you would change the default working behavior of Nuxt's project structure. What do you mean (`not meant to be run on a server`), you don't want to have it hosted somewhere, only planning to use it with `yarn dev`?

Comment: Except there is some security issue or some other technical reason, I think relative paths is a no-brainer. It allows the generated website function in any deployment circumstance: e.g. deploying to root the folder or 10th level of sub-folder.